# Running Excel Solver Macro in Coldfusion

Tags: excel, coldfusion, solver

I'm trying to run the excel solver in Coldfusion. However i'm running into issues like, the page hangs as if loading forever, similar to [this](http://www.justskins.com/forums/using-excel-solver-through-coldfusion-61909.html).

Is it possible to run excel solver thru Coldfusion? If not, are there other alternatives for Coldfusion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have Excel installed on the ColdFusion server?

Comment: Yes. actually, i can open any excel file, no problem. But when i add the solver add-in to any excel file, the page seems to hang when trying to open the excel file.

Comment: what version of excel? that code is quite old - maybe your COM references are wrong. do you get any errors in the CF admin logs? Or in the Event Viewer?

Comment: Also, does the user account CF is running under have access to the Excel app?

Answer (score 2):

Running Office applications server-side is definitely not recommended by Microsoft.

See [KB257757 - Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757) for explanations and suggestions.

ColdFusion itself has (very probably) nothing to do with your problem.